# Why isnt this Jquery if statement working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

http://streamplex.us/web/smartphone-services/ this is the site I am working on. I am trying to get it so the height of the `.services-wrap` changes on wether or not `#samsung-repair` is open.

```
<script> //Services Toggle
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#samsung").click(function(){
        $("#samsung-repair").toggle("slide", 300);
      });

      $("#iphone").click(function(){
        $("#iphone-repair").toggle("slide", 300, function() {
            $("#computer-repair-img").toggleClass("section-pad", 300, function() {
               if($("samsung-repair").is(':visible')){
                   $(".services-wrap").css({"height" : "355px"});
               } else if ($("samsung-repair").is(':hidden')) {
                   $(".services-wrap").css({"height" : "700px"}); 
               }; 
            }); 
        });
      });

      $("#computer").click(function(){
        $("#computer-repair").toggle("slide", 300);
      });

    });
    </script>
```

Thank you guys I got it just they way I want it to work now.

```
  $("#iphone").click(function(){
    $("#iphone-repair").toggle("slide", 300, function() {
           if($("#samsung-repair").is(':visible')){
               $("#computer-repair-img").toggleClass("section-pad", 300);
           } else if ($("#samsung-repair").is(':hidden')) {
               $(".services-wrap").toggleClass("section-height", 300); 
           };  
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if($("#samsung-repair").is(':visible')){  //put '#'  here
```

and here also

```
 else if ($("#samsung-repair").is(':hidden')) {  //put '#' here
```

Comment: I reselected yours I'm sorry I didnt realize it would uncredit you. I thought it was selecting his as correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the div with `$("samsung-repair")`, but it should be `$("#samsung-repair")`.